# Firestore Validate Date (Value for argument "seconds" must be within [-62135596800, 253402300799] inclusive)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a batched write against firebase at the same time I create a user with an email.

```
   try {
    // Get a new Firestore batched write
    const batch = firestore.batch();

    // Generate an user uuid
    const userId = uuidv4();

    // Create the new username document in the usernames collection with the user's id as field
    const usernameRef = firestore.collection("usernames").doc(username);
    batch.set(usernameRef, { userId });

    // Create the new user document in the users collection with all the relevant information
    const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(userId);

    // Pass the username to lower case
    username = username.toLowerCase();

    // Take the birthday milliseconds and convert it back to a Date
    birthday = new Date(birthday);

    const data = {
      email,
      username,
      name,
      birthday,
    };

    batch.set(userRef, data);

    // Create the user with Firebase Authentication
    await admin.auth().createUser({
      uid: userId,
      email,
      password,
    });

    // Commit the batch
    await batch.commit(); 

  } catch(err) {
    ...
  }
```

With this, a user will not be added to the db if the email is already taken. But there is a problem, if the birthday is invalid for Firestore, the exception will be catched in the batch commit... so the email will be registered.

Is there any way to validate the date value before commiting it to firestore? For example, if I do

```
  birthday = new Date(-182397382409)
```

this will throw an error.

> Value for argument "seconds" must be within [-62135596800, 253402300799] inclusive

Also, the problem will be solved if admin.createUser was included in the batched write too, but I don't know if that is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: you could validate `birthday`

Comment: The thing is that firestore autoconvert js dates to {seconds: (not date.getSeconds()) , nanoseconds: } object. And I don't know how to validate a js date to have the seconds of the firestore object between [-62135596800, 253402300799] inclusive.

Comment: divide milliseconds js date by 1000?

Comment: @DougStevenson sure, but there are only 1000 milliseconds in a second ... javascript dates are in milliseconds ... the code above does `birthday = new Date(birthday)` ... so, `birthday` (before the conversion to Date object) must be in milliseconds, not nanoseconds - my suggestion was validating `birthday` before converting it to a date ... so in fact would have to make sure `birthday/1000` falls within the allowed range (since `"seconds" must be within [-62135596800, 253402300799]` )

Comment: @JaromandaX Sounds like an answer, then.

Comment: @DougStevenson - well, sure, but I don't know how to validate in the context of the code shown, as the code shown shows no place where validation should take place

Comment: @JaromandaX How about as soon as possible?

Comment: I have the form validation in a function and do it before the code I have shown. Also, I have done what you said and works! Thank you!

Comment: @Raul If you want to answer your own question, please do.

Comment: @DougStevenson - but how to indicate invalid data :p but OP has responded now, so, he should answer own question

Comment: @JaromandaX The question just asked how to validate, not how to indicate.

Comment: I have answered it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating the user in the db and with the authentication email, I validate all the client form and then run the code in the question.

### Here is the form validation

```
async function validateForm(
  username,
  email,
  password,
  repeatPassword,
  name,
  birthday,
  clientIp
) {
  ... Validate data types, availabilities in the db, regex (including password strength), ...

  // Validate the user's birthday
  if (!validateBirthday(birthday)) {
    return "The birthday is not valid";
  }
}

validateBirthday = function (birthday) {
  /* Birthday has to be in milliseconds since unix epoch */

  // Get the birthday in seconds
  const birthdayInSeconds = birthday / 1000;

  return birthdayInSeconds >= -62135596800 && birthdayInSeconds <= 253402300799
}
```

### The full code

```
// Validate the form data
const feedback = await validateForm(
  username,
  email,
  password,
  repeatPassword,
  name,
  birthday,
  clientIp
);

// If the form has been validated and no feedback has been received...
if (!feedback) {
  try {
    // Get a new Firestore batched write
    const batch = firestore.batch();

    // Generate an user uuid
    const userId = uuidv4();

    // Create the new username document in the usernames collection with the user's id as field
    const usernameRef = firestore.collection("usernames").doc(username);
    batch.set(usernameRef, { userId });

    // Create the new user document in the users collection with all the relevant information
    const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(userId);

    // Pass the username to lower case
    username = username.toLowerCase();

    // Take the birthday milliseconds and convert it back to a Date
    birthday = new Date(birthday);

    const data = {
      email,
      username,
      name,
      birthday,
    };

    batch.set(userRef, data);

    // Create the user with Firebase Authentication
    await admin.auth().createUser({
      uid: userId,
      email,
      password,
    });

    // Commit the batch
    await batch.commit(); 

  } catch(err) {
    ...
  }
} else {
   // Throw feedback to the user
}
```